# htaccess file from Apache to Nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am building a dynamic site to a friend and I'm using nginx web server with. The site has been designed locally with Apache and now I have a .htaccess file that I need to convert to add it in the configuration file for nginx. .htaccess Does is hide the extension of .php pages and give an error if you call a page with the extension. Here is the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !404.php$ 
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*) 404.php [L]
```

Here is the configuration file nginx

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name MY_SERVER_IP_IS_HERE;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ = /error/404.html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri /index.php =404;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME      
$document_root$fastcgi_script_nam$
include fastcgi_params;
}
location / { 
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php break;
if ($request_uri ~ "\.php"){
rewrite ([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*) /404.php break;
                           } 
}
}
```

Comment: Have you at all tried anything? This looks like a *do-my-homework-for-me* question.

Comment: I tried to translate using http://winginx.com/en/htaccess I put the rules in the configuration file and restart nginx I once got a syntax error.

Comment: Put your `nginx.conf`!